# Always have this error 'IndexError: string index out of range', when i have taken into consideration of index range

Tags: python

Need to write a program that prints the longest substring of variable, in which the letters occur in alphabetical order.

eg. `s = 'onsjdfjqiwkvftwfbx'`, it should returns `'dfjq'`.

as a beginner, code written as below:

```
y=()
z=()
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    letter=s[i]
    while s[i]<=s[i+1]:
        letter+=s[i+1]
        i+=1
    y=y+(letter,)
    z=z+(len(letter),)
print(y[z.index(max(z))])
```

However, above code will always return

```
IndexError: string index out of range.
```

It will produce the desired result until I change it to `range(len(s)-3)`.

Would like to seek advice on:

1. Why `range(len(s)-1)` will lead to such error message? In order to take care of index up to i+1, I have already reduce the range value by 1.
   my rationale is, if the length of variable s is 14, it has index from 0-13, range(14) produce value 0-13. However as my code involves i+1 index, range is reduced by 1 to take care of this part.
2. How to amend above code to produce correct result.
   if `s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`, above code with **range(len(s)-3)** returns `IndexError: string index out of range` again. Why? what's wrong with this code?

Any help is appreciated~

Comment: Please don't add code as images, it makes it hard to read, hard to search and nearly impossible for those with accessibility issues such as low eyesight to read. You're using `i` inside the `while` loop and incrementing it there, comparing the values of the array to decide when you're going to stop. That's not going to end automagically because of the outer range, so your inner `i += 1` is cause the index `i` to be incremented beyond the length of the string.

Comment: Tks for pointing out, have alr amended.    @MatsLindh, would you please elaborate? I don't quite understand how should I amend the code.

Answer (score 0):

Te reason for the out of range index is that in your internal `while` loop, you are advancing `i` without checking for its range. Your code is also very inefficient, as you have nested loops, and you are doing a lot of relatively expensive string concatenation. A linear time algorithm without concatenations would look something like this:

```
s = 'onsjdfjqiwkvftwfbcdefgxa'

# Start by assuming the longest substring is the first letter
longest_end = 0
longest_length = 1
length = 1

for i in range(1, len(s)):
    if s[i] > s[i - 1]:
        # If current character higher in order than previous increment current length
        length += 1
        if length > longest_length:
            # If current length, longer than previous maximum, remember position
            longest_end = i + 1
            longest_length = length
    else:
        # If not increasing order, reset current length
        length = 1

print(s[longest_end - longest_length:longest_end])
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this alternative. However, notice if s = 'hdppsbsmxmfgynz', above code could not provide the correct answer of 'dpps' apparently.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding "1":**
Actually, using `range(len(s)-2)` should also work.

The reason `range(len(s)-1)` breaks:

For 'onsjdfjqiwkvftwfbx', the `len()` will be equal to 18. Still, the max index you can refer is 17 (since indexing starts at 0).
Thus, when you loop through "i"'s, at some point, i will increase to 17 (which corresponds to `len(s)-1`) and then try access `s[i+1]` in your `while` comparison (which is impossible).

**Regarding "2":**
The following should work:

```
current_output = ''
biggest_output = ''
for letter in s:
    if current_output == '':
        current_output += letter
    else:
        if current_output[-1]<=letter:
            current_output += letter
        else:
            if len(current_output) > len(biggest_output):
                biggest_output = current_output
            current_output = letter

if len(current_output) > len(biggest_output):
    biggest_output = current_output
    
print(biggest_output)
```

Comment: Hi~ thanks for pointing out the prob with while loop in this case. Tried above code for s = 'hdppsbsmxmfgynz', but it couldn't generate the correct string of 'dpps' either.

Comment: @hanami you are right - I made. a typo. Please check the edited version.

Comment: @hanami Could you please comment if my revised answer solved your problem?